# How to install a MWF water filter for GE refrigerator

Tags: water

I am not able to install MWF water filter cartridge in my GE refrigerator.
Instructions say to align arrows.  I don't see 2 arrows to align. Align where?

Comment: With the arrows! No, seriously, how can anyone help you without the model number of your refrigerator? There are well over 30 different ge models out there... Post the model number of the fridge.... Why are you installing a MWF filter? Is that what was there already?